# Github Actions modify repo

Tags: git, github-actions

I need to update package.json file version everytime I push to master branch. I have this code:

```
name: "Bump version"

on: 
  push:
    branches: 
     - "master"


jobs: 
  bump-version: 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
      - name: "Checkout code"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with: 
          node-version: '14'
      - name: 'Update version'
        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          npm version patch -m 'update version'
          git add .
          git commit -am "Update version"
          git push
```

I am getting an error that : `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.`. I am not sure what the issue is. At first I was getting an error that git didnt know who I am so I set some random config user.name and user.email. I am new to actions and command line tools so any help would be appreciated. Also I would eventually want to check if the commit has the string major in it and update the package version from 1.0.0 -> 2.0.0. Im not sure how to do that using actions

Comment: Can you explain what commands you are using in the terminal and where you are seeing errors? Is that error in your terminal?

Comment: The github action runs and causes an error `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit`

Comment: @JBaczuk ^^^^^^

Comment: can you post the full output from the github action?

Comment: That's not an *error* (you made a new commit, so of course you are one commit ahead now), and what you've shown here is all normal behavior that you should expect. You'll need to augment this question with what *else* you are, or are not, seeing, vs what you expect to see.